# "Neither they nor I am going to buy lunch"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I know the verb should agrees with the closest noun (or pronoun). But I feel "are" is better with the following context.

Anyway, which one of them is correct and more common?

> - Neither they nor I **am** going to buy lunch.
> - Neither they nor I **are** going to buy lunch.

**Update:** 
I know it is better to rewrite the sentence in another way to avoid this scenario.

Is the secound one grammatically correct?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122969/controversy-over-verb-choice-in-neither-you-nor-i-is-am-are-in-control and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/390808/what-verb-neither-you-nor-i

Answer (score 1):

As most guides say ([one of them](http://grammarguide.copydesk.org/2012/01/10/a-tricky-agreement-problem-neither-nor/)), the tricky issue about **Neither-nor** and **Either-or** is that:

1. When two or more subjects are joined, you should focus on the subject closest to the verb:

   - **Neither** my brother **nor** my sister **was** at school today. **(Not were!)**
   - **Neither** Michael **nor** his friends **are** going there tonight. **(Not is!)**
2. If you have a plural and a singular noun joined it is better to place the plural last to avoid awkward sentences.

   - **Neither** I **nor** my friends **have** ever been to that cafe. **(Not has!)**
3. With a plural and a singular noun joined once a plural comes first both plural or singular verb is possible. And as far as I am concerned this isn't bad grammar:

   - **Neither** his parents **nor** he **was** at home.
   - **Neither** his parents **nor** he **were** at home.

Yet, it's better to rephrase it to:

- **Neither** he **nor** his parents **were** at home.

Of your two sentences:

1. *Neither they nor I am going to buy lunch.*
2. *Neither they nor I are going to buy lunch.*

The first one is correct but the most correct sentence should be:

- **Neither** I **nor** they **are** going to buy lunch.

[More examples:](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp)

1. **Neither** the plates **nor** the serving bowl **goes** on that shelf.
2. **Neither** the serving bowl **nor** the plates **go** on that shelf.

Answer (score -2):

Your example sentences should be using 'they' rather than 'them'

> - Neither they nor I **am** going to buy lunch.

This usage of the word **am** in this sentence is wrong/incorrect.

> - Neither they nor I **are** going to buy lunch.

This sentence is correct; it uses valid grammar.

Comment: Thank you, I'll update the grammar in the question, but why "are" not "am"

Comment: @Shannak: Unfortunately, while I can recognize good and bad English usage and grammar, this is due to my speaking English all my life and also reading tens of thousands of books in English. I don't remember much of the formal rules as taught to me when I was young. I can't tell you the rule that proves why the use of 'am' your example is incorrect, but my brain insists that this is true. If I had to guess I would say that 'am' is singular (I am), while 'are' is plural (they are). Using either 'I are' or 'they am' would be incorrect usage.

Comment: While the advice on this subject is *to rewrite the sentence to avoid the issue*, this example definitely sounds better with the plural: *Neither the thousands of supporters nor my father WERE happy with the ref's decision.*

Comment: @Shannak, because "they + I" equals "we" and we should use "are" with "we."

Comment: But we use "nor" between them, "Neither he nor she is going ...".